# How does a seudat mitzvah exempt you from fasting?

Tags: fast-days, meal-seudah, siyum, petur-exemption

Apparently, you can become exempt from certain fasts (such as the [fast of the firstborn](http://www.chabad.org/holidays/passover/pesach_cdo/aid/1741/jewish/Fast-of-the-Firstborn.htm)) by making a seudat mitzvah, particularly a siyum.

Why/how is this possible?

If it is because you are eating that meal l'shem mitzvah, (1) what is the evidence that such a meal is truly l'shem mitzvah (i.e., is it commanded somewhere that one must make a meal upon completion of a learning section?); (2) why can't we do that for any fast; and (3) does that mean you must still fast for the rest of the day, besides the seudah?

"Food" for thought, maybe a separate question: Is there any obligation to do your l'shem mitzvah stuff in a way that it will not get in the way of other mitzvot--if easily possible? (Such as, in this case, making your siyyum on a different day from the fast...)

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48237&st=&pgnum=124&hilite=

Comment: @GershonGold, who is the mechaber of that sefer (Tzvi Reisman)?

Comment: One of the notei keilim to Shulchan Aruch (perhaps the sh"a itself, I don't recall the shiur exactly) rules that when Ta'anit Tisha b'Av is pushed off to the next day, the ba'alei hasimchah for a bris should wash themselves and have a festive meal, despite it being a fast day.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt You mean he should do so on the "new" date of Tisha b'Av, right?

Comment: @SAH, when the fast is deferred to the tenth. I have heard this referred to as Ta'anit Av, rather than Tisha b'Av.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt I've also heard "Tisha B'av Nidche" for this